# Hacking own computer

Tags: penetration-test

Ok I've worked with some penetration testing but it's all done in house where I work at on a secure network to secure servers and work stations before being deployed. But my question here is kind of vague on the laws of the U.S. 
I want to show my girlfriends son who is interested in my line of work some examples of hacking, but I can not bring him to where I work because they live two hours away from me.

So my question here is, would it be illegal for me to set up one of my personal servers or computers on my home network and then actually hack into it from her house with in the same state? I would be using all my personally owned equipment (ie. laptop, server, desktop PC, routers and cable modems) only thing I wouldn't own is the internet itself, that is owned and controlled by bright house networks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advise. Such questions should only be answered by a legal professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, nor do I know anything about being a lawyer. Although I do understand what is required to perform a pentest against a clients systems.

As you are attacking your own device, you are likely not breaking any laws. As you have express permissions from your girlfriend (I would hope so), to perform this task it will likely be safe to perform this.

As this is based on the legality if you have the proper approval to perform the pentest you are likely safe on this. (again I want to stress my disclaimer).

Answer (score 4):

For demonstration purposes, I personally would just create a few virtual machines, and demonstrate what you can do to them locally. As mentioned, placing a vulnerable machine on the internet is just a bad idea. If you can hack into it, so can others... and as my firewall logs indicate, there's always someone poking around...

Comment: The server I will be using has nothing important on it. It's just a file server holding nothing but music, movies, and is constantly neglected when it comes to updates and patches. I have a secondary server on a separate isolated network in my apartment that houses all my important files, family pictures and emails.

Answer (score 0):

Bringing up the lawyer point mentioned by @m3r1n I had in the past been hired to check out a machine for an individual who was concerned about being hacked by her ex., to look for spyware or other misconduct. This was prelude to a lawsuit. He did not as it turned out, but if he had, and she was unaware or otherwise not understanding of what he was doing, he would have been in real trouble.

Comment: Monitoring your significant other or someone whom you are in a relationship with for the purpose of prying into there personal life, as I am aware is illegal and can you can be brought to court on these grounds.

Comment: Yes monitoring your spouse or significant other is illegal. However if the person in question is your child and under the age of 18 it's not illegal. We deal with this legal question day in and day out here

Answer (score 0):

**[IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL)** and all that but from a legal standpoint hacking you own machine should be fine, even if it was illegal, your unlikely to press charges against yourself.

The one word of caution though is to watch out for collateral damage, if you have done pen-testing before your probably already aware of this. There are some things you might not think of, for example I was running a bunch of [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) scans from my home against my work's public IP range just to check the firewall was doing what I though it was.

That was all ok and above board but I'd forgot to inform my work ISP and their [IDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_Detection_System) picked it up and automatically sent an email to aubse@HomeISP saying they had seen suspicious from my home IP address.

Also I'm not sure how you plan on setting it up having a publicly facing vulnerable server is not a great idea. If you intentionally set up a vulnerable server, then it got hacked and used maliciously you might be in a legally grey area and it might violate your ISP's Terms of Service.

If you are planning on connecting through a VPN or some sort of secure tunnel and then attacking the server you should be fine.

Comment: The server I will be using has nothing important on it. It's just a file server holding nothing but music, movies, and is constantly neglected when it comes to updates and patches. I have a secondary server on a separate isolated network in my apartment that houses all my important files, family pictures and emails.

Comment: The point was more about what if someone gets on it and starts using it for something malicious. Someone in Austria was [arrested for running a tor exit node](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20140701/18013327753/tor-nodes-declared-illegal-austria.shtml). Imagen if someone hacked it and started downloading/sharing highly illegal material, you might be liable.

Comment: Even still the server would be DOD secure wiped once done. Once done with demonstration I would just shut it down through rdp so it can't be accessed until I get back home and scan through it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer, but most hacking laws actually come down to being trespassing laws.  If you are using a computer system, you are only allowed to use it in the way that the owner intended.  Since you are the owner of both systems, you are using it the way the owner intended, since you intended it as a demonstration of penetration testing.

If this wasn't the case, sites like hackthissite.org would be illegal to use, but that isn't the case.  There are some special case laws like laws about bypassing protections on smartphones now being illegal, but that is mostly special case stuff and I'm not personally aware of anything that would make something like what you are talking about illegal.

That said, the concern about people breaking in to your system is a valid concern.  You may not have anything of value on the server, but you forget that the server itself is likely more valuable than the data on it.  If someone can compromise your server, they can use it as a launching point for their own attacks on other systems and if the people they attack point out that you should have known better, they might be able to hold you liable for putting an exposed system out there (not sure if this has been tried or not, but it may be a possibility).

Your best bet is really to use one of the multiple sites out there that already have demonstration boxes set up in a secure way where they appear to be able to be compromised, but are really just running a super sandboxed simulation that lets you demonstrate the basic techniques without actually having a system open to real compromise.  [Hackthissite.org](http://hackthissite.org) is my personal favorite of these, though it isn't the only one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually buy your cable modem (and your girlfriend's), or did it come with your Internet package? If the latter, it is not "personally owned equipment". Neither, under any circumstance, are the intermediate infrastructure devices through which you will connect from across the Internet - some of which may not even be controlled by Bright House.

Laws regarding computer crimes are still very much under development and are often being applied to cases where defendants may reasonably have assumed they have not done anything wrong.

The best way to avoid being caught in these undefined nets is to just avoid using any equipment other than your own (or equipment to which you've been explicitly granted completely unrestricted use, or particularly permitted to use for penetration testing, in writing) for things like this. Make a pentesting lab with VMs on a portable computer (here, "portable" may include a desktop or small server), take that to your girlfriend's house, and *never* connect it to the Internet while it's being used for your pentest demo.